# Split string and number and store on key-value pair

Tags: c#, split, key-value

I'm trying to scrap a bunch of similar HTML pages and the tags are a nightmare IMHO.
I found that using,

```
IList<IWebElement> all = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("p"));
```

brought quite goood results. Here's the different strings I can get using it:

```
1 txt 2 txt txt txt, 3 txt txt.
4 txt
5 txt 6 txt
7 txt

"txt
txt
txt"

8 txt.
```

I basically want to separate numbers and text preserving their relation.
Essentially, each line is a different string (which is a different p element), including the empty ones.
The best way I could think was to generate a key value pair, but I was not able to extract numbers and text and preserve their relation.
I'm trying to do it with using the Split method

```
Regex.Split(input, pattern);
```

which I think won't work very well on these strings. Any thoughts? The desired result would be a list like:

```
1: [1, txt]
2: [2, txt txt txt,]
3: [3, txt.]
4: [4, txt]
5: [5, txt] 
6: [6, txt] 
7: [7, txt "txt txt txt"] 
8: [8, txt.]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
int key = -100; string value = "";
foreach(IWebElement element in all)
{
        foreach (var str in element.Text.Split(' '))
        {     
            int new_key;

            if (int.TryParse(str.Trim(), out new_key))
            {
                if (value == "")
                    key = new_key;
                else
                {
                    dict[key] = value.Trim();
                    value = "";
                    key = new_key;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                value += str + " ";
            }

        }
        dict[key] = value.Trim();
}
```

my code does assume that there will be no integer words in the text like "1 txt txt txt 3 txt" where 3 is part of text not key. Whenever there is an integer, this code will assume it to be a key for the dictionary.

Comment: Great code Hamad, but unfortunately it doesnt get strings with no number. For example, in that example, 7 come as 7, txt instead of 7, txt "txt txt txt". Debugging, it turns out every end of string, the counter returns to -100 and it saves it on key=-100.

Comment: Proposed an edit. Sending the initialization to outside the first foreach, fixes this. 7 turns out to be correct now.